# create {brackets}=$array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Is it possible to define the following  {bracketsvalue}=$array , so that {bracketsvalue} gets replaced with the contents of the array when the php is processed ?.

The reason I ask is I have a form where I have {firstname} {businessname}, these are the fields first name and business name, what I want to do is just have a template with :
Dear {name},
bla bla bla bla

but name isnt a form field, I want it to be dynamically generated like the following :

$namearray = 
if firstname field is blank
echo business name
else
echo firstname field

and then something like {name} = $namearray
so when {name} is inserted it will echo the result of the if statement.

Comment: Have you looked at templating libraries such as Smarty or Mustache?

Comment: I looked at smarty but it looked a bit confusing, Mustache looks more stright forward though so might try that

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to implement very simple templating:

```
/**
 * Render a given template
 *
 * @param string $template Template text
 * @param array  $data     List of values of placeholder variables (associative)
 */
function render($template, $data)
{
    foreach ( array_keys($data) as $holder ) {
        $template = str_replace('{' . strtoupper($holder) . '}', $data[$holder], $template);
    }
    return nl2br($template);
}
```

Then {NAME} will get the value of $data['name'], etc.

Comment: Use `nl2br()` instead of that final `str_replace(PHP_EOL, ...)`